# Universal windows app to send data from one page to another

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I had partitioned the `MainPage.xaml` in two parts. The Left part has some buttons which will give command to change the Right part with new Page. So I created three right pages for ex. `RightPage1`, `RightPage2` and `RightPage3`. The problem is that, I want to show data on Left part after the operations done on `RightPage1`, 2 or 3.
Should I follow some pattern to fulfill this approach? or we can do it directly in code behind?

All I researched is giving me solution to navigate to that page and send the data in parameter. But I don't want to open the page again, because it's already opened on the Left side of `MainPage`. Please help me to solve this situation.

In RightPage 1, on Submit Click Event I want to show some message in `MainPage.xaml`'s Left part in `TextBlock` lblClassName.

```
HomePage.xaml

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <RelativePanel>
        <Button x:Name="btn1"
                Content="Button 1"
                Height="50" Width="100" Margin="0,30,0,0"
                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                Click="btn1_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn2"
                Content="Button 2"
                Height="50" Width="100" Margin="0,30,0,0"
                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.Below="btn1"
                Click="btn2_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn3"
                Content="Button 3"
                Height="50" Width="100" Margin="0,30,0,0"
                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.Below="btn2"
                Click="btn3_Click"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="lblWrite"
                   Text="Write something : "
                   Visibility="Visible"
                   RelativePanel.Below="btn3"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtWrite"
                 Height="50" Width="150"
                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                 RelativePanel.Below="lblWrite"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn3_1"
                Height="50" Width="100"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Content="Send"
                RelativePanel.Below="txtWrite"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="lblClassName"/>

    </RelativePanel>
    <Frame x:Name="RightPage"
           Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>


RightPage1.xaml

<Grid Background="Beige">
        <TextBlock x:Name="heading"
                   Text="Teacher Module"
                   RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblName"
                   Text="Name" Margin="0,30,0,0"
                   RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.Below="heading"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtName"
                 Height="30" Width="150" Margin="30,30,0,0"
                 RelativePanel.RightOf="lblName"
                 RelativePanel.Below="heading"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblClass"
                   Text="Class" Margin="0,30,0,0"
                   RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.Below="lblName"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtClass"
                 Height="30" Width="150" Margin="30,10,0,0"
                 RelativePanel.RightOf="lblClass"
                 RelativePanel.Below="txtName"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSumbit"
                Content="Submit"
                Height="50" Width="100" Margin="0,30,0,0"
                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.Below="lblClass"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnCancel"
                Content="Cancel"
                Height="50" Width="100" Margin="30,30,0,0"
                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.Below="lblClass"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="btnSumbit"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="lblResult"
                   Margin="0,30,0,0"
                   RelativePanel.Below="btnSumbit"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can do it directly in code behind. For example:

In the code-behind of HomePage.xaml, we can define a static field in `HomePage` that represent the `HomePage` itself and add a public method to change the `TextBlock`'s text.

```
public sealed partial class HomePage : Page
{
    //define a static field represent the HomePage itself
    public static HomePage Home;

    public HomePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //initialize Home field
        Home = this;
    }

    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Show some message in TextBlock lblClassName
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">message to been shown</param>
    public void ChangeMessage(string message)
    {
        this.lblClassName.Text = message;
    }
}
```

Then in Submit Click event, we can call `ChangeMessage` method to show the message.

```
private void btnSumbit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HomePage.Home?.ChangeMessage("The message you want to show");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, I can do in this way, but I don't just want to show textMessage. My problem is something like I have two ViewModels and One Model, so I want to show changes on both views done by any one of Viewmodels. I searched for the answers and I come to the point that I have to create one DataService which will update the All Viewmodels which are using updated Model. But I didn't get any article to implement the same.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the only way, if any other way is there, please help.

Comment: @AnkitSaini If you are using MVVM pattern, the answer might be different. I'd suggest you ask a new question with the details of your MVVM pattern such as how your ViewModels and Model implemented and what you want to achieve. You can use some fake date. It will make your question easier to understand and you can get much better answers.